# How redirect STDOUT streams of 2 commands to each others STDIN?

Tags: shell

I need to do something like

```
~$ command1 | command2 | command1
```

And the third one should not be another instance of the same program, but the same process. Bad English, not sure that I have explained correctly, so here's one more attempt to say what I mean in some different way..

I expect the following to be done:
Program1 prints something, Program2 scans what Program1 has printed, Program2 prints something, Program1 scans what Program2 has printed and so on. Excuse me, if detailed learning of BASH would do the trick, my fault, but I didn't find any opportune solution via Google.

Comment: Maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53641/how-to-make-bidirectional-pipe-between-two-programs?

Comment: Maybe you mean `command2` is a coprocess of `command1`... http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/keywords/coproc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general and taken as it stands, your question doesn't make much sense because it talks about two processing entities (processes) in a circle.  This situation is a hen/egg situation and calls for the question where did it start and how does it end.

So maybe you want to tell us something more about your concrete use case, and then we maybe can give better advice on a different level to solve your problem at hand.

But taken as it stands, just a little more liberally, I think @mark-setchell's comment aims at the thing you might want to do.  Sounds like your `command2` is a coroutine of `command1`, meaning that it is a thing running in parallel, receiving data and handing back data on demand.  The `bash` knows such a thing and supports it, but this is not widely used, so don't expect much support for it anywhere.

An example maybe illustrates the use:

```
coproc SED while read a; do echo "$a" | sed 's/x/u/g'; done
ls -l 1>&${SED[1]}
cat 0<&${SED[0]}
```

- This creates a coroutine (`coproc`) to the current shell which runs a loop, reading lines, replacing the `x` by `u` in the lines, then output them again.
- Then it calls `ls -l` and sends the output into the running coroutine.
- The last line finally reads the output of the existing coroutine and prints it to stdout.

The last two steps can be done repeatedly because the coroutine keeps running.

Comment: In pure C I want to do things, that in C++ are done with pthread. In my case it's supposed to be done by the operating system itself. Is it real?

Comment: Don't change your question, please ;-)  You asked about shell stuff, not about C/C++ stuff.  You are of course free to post follow-up questions about varying aspects, with reference to this question.

Comment: I just pointed what I mean by this. As in C++ you may do this with 2 strings (thread1 sscanf-s *S1 and sprintf-s *S2, thread2 sscanf-s *S2 and sprintf-s *S1), the similar stuff I want to be done with pipes, when I have two monothread programs. Of course I'm going to teach the both to understand each other well enough to avoid infinite loop. Thank you for aiming at COPROC, I'll discover the subject.